# Map as a function parameter in java

Tags: java

I am writing a function which takes two map as argument
Here is my code

```
    public static Map<String, ArrayList<String> > getFavouriteGenres(Map<String, ArrayList<String> > userMovies, Map<String, ArrayList<String> > movieGenres)
    {
        
        Map<String, ArrayList<String>> genreMovies = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

        for (Map.Entry m:movieGenres.entrySet()){
            //ArrayList<String> list = m.getValue();  
            for (String mov:m.getValue()){
                ArrayList<String> l = genreMovies.containsKey(mov) ? genreMovies.get(mov):new ArrayList<String>();
                genreMovies.put(mov, l.add(m.getKey()));
            }                            
        }
    //other implementation
```

On compilation I am getting following error

```
StreamingApp.java:17: error: for-each not applicable to expression type
            for (String mov:m.getValue()){
                                      ^
  required: array or java.lang.Iterable
  found:    Object
StreamingApp.java:19: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String
                genreMovies.put(mov, l.add(m.getKey()));
```

How to solve it ?

Comment: you need `for(Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> m:movieGenres.entrySet())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `Map.Entry` as a raw type. That means all generics of it and anything derived from it are also blank. Thus, `m.getValue()` returns `Object` and not `ArrayList<String>`.

The solution is to add the generics appropriately:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> m : movieGenres.entrySet()) {
    List<String> list = m.getValue();
   ...
}
```

that's a mouthful. Fortunately, you can write that a lot more simply:

```
for (var m : movieGenries.entrySet()) {
    List<String> list = m.getValue();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Well, then the first mouthful is the only solution, which fortunately is in the answer, so not sure if that's worth mentioning.

Comment: Perhaps adding a note like "If you are using Java 10 or later..." since the OP did not indicate version.

Comment: I have java 11.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for (Map.Entry m:movieGenres.entrySet()){
```

TO

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> m:movieGenres.entrySet()){
```

AND

```
genreMovies.put(mov, l.add(m.getKey()));
```

TO

```
l.add(m.getKey());
genreMovies.put(mov, l);
```